# Jehovah's Witnesses - What is the reasoning that led to 1914 being considered a significant year?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, chronology

Looks like there are a few questions here about Jehovah's Witnesses viewing 1914 as a significant year in the history of mankind, but not much about what their reasoning has been for that.

The other question that is claimed as duplicate does not address the question.

What is the **biblical/historical/mathematical/etc reasoning** that led Jehovah's Witnesses to believe in the significance of 1914?

Comment: Thanks @User14, nothing in that explains how or why 1914 specifically.

Comment: https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/bible-teach/1914-significant-year-bible-prophecy/    Here is a stsrt

Comment: I have voted to close as the previous, accepted answer fully provides for this one as well - [Lesley](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/86604/38350)

Comment: And here https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/enjoy-life-forever/section-2/lesson-32/

Comment: @Alec Interpretations of specificity which determine whether a question is a duplicate or not can be frustrating. I've had questions I thought were different closed because someone else thought they were duplicates. Alas! I think this is an interesting, relevantly different question, even if the linked question has an answer to it.